# Error creating new project with Haskell Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Right now I'm not able to do `stack new my-project` anywhere in my filesystem.  When I do, I get

```
| => stack new my-project
Downloading template "new-template" to create project "my-project" in my-project/ ...

Looking for .cabal or package.yaml files to use to init the project.
Using cabal packages:
- my-project/my-project.cabal

Selecting the best among 12 snapshots...

Downloaded lts-10.2 build plan.
AesonException "Error in $.packages.cassava.constraints.flags['bytestring--lt-0_10_4']: Invalid flag name: \"bytestring--lt-0_10_4\""
```

This prevents me from setting up and building the project:

```
| => cd my-project; stack build
Error parsing targets: The specified targets matched no packages.
Perhaps you need to run 'stack init'?
```

I have Stack Version 1.5.1 and GHC 8.0.2.  What could be causing this?  I'm really at a loss.  I haven't found anything documented online similar to what I'm describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as https://github.com/fpco/stackage/issues/2759 .
Upgrade stack to v1.6.1

Comment: Yes, just found this.  Thank you.